# <fb:like> button does not work in IE8

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

This problem is really killing me, I have been googling for a VERY long time now and I just CAN'T find the answer to this.

The problem is that my LIKE button does not render on IE8 (internet explorer 8) but it does show on chrome.

Here is a url to a test page:
http://78.69.194.141/vinn/test.php

If you are using not using IE8 you should see a like button under "h5 header".

This is the related code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fbstyle.css" />
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '195633697119592',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelURL : 'http://78.69.194.141/vinn/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
  FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function(a,b){FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id]=b;};
</script>
```

and the button:

```
<fb:like layout="button_count"></fb:like>
```

I've tried many different ways, loading the js async and every other way mentioned on internet but with results.

It seems like this problem only occurs on my server though, because those like buttons work on other places, with EXACT same code (afaik).

Does anyone have ANY clue?

Comment: Likely something either in your DOM (invalid html and the like) or you have other JS that is throwing an error in IE. I don't have my virtual machine for IE8 set up at the moment or I'd take a closer look at your test URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE8 throws this error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined 
>   all.js, line 6 character 1252

It's referring to the iframe which facebook replaces the `<fb:like>` tag with which suggests that either the setup options for the button are wrong, or there is invalid HTML on the page which is messing up the DOM so the JavaScript can't find the iframe.

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2f78.69.194.141%2fvinn%2ftest.php

A good place to start would be to put in `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing `<head>` tags and `<body>` elements together and not defining the sections properly.  You need a `<head>` section for the `<link>` tag (and possibly some `<script>` tags) and a `<body>` section for elements like `<div>`.  As it stands, your page is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to add `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"` to `<html>` tag, like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```